# Question with expectation of probability mass function of random variable

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The probability mass function of random variable $X$ is given by $$P(X=i)=e^{-2}*\frac{2^{i}}{i!}, i=0,1,2,....$$ Find the expectation, $E[X]$.

I know that, 
$$E[X]=\sum_{x, p(x)>0}xp(x)$$

I am just struggling understanding the problem.

Comment: Have you tried plugging in appropriate parts into the definition?

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

$$p(x) = P(X=x)$$

A formula that might help you, $$e^\lambda = \sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\Bbb P(X=i)=p(i)=\mathrm e^{-2}\times\frac{2^{i}}{i!},\qquad i=0,\,1,\,2,\ldots$$
So we have

$$
\begin{align}\Bbb E(X)&=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i\,p(i)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i\mathrm e^{-2}\frac{2^{i}}{i!}\\
&=\mathrm e^{-2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{i}}{(i-1)!}=2\mathrm e^{-2}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{i-1}}{(i-1)!}\\
&=2\mathrm e^{-2}\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{k}}{k!}}_{\mathrm e^2}=2\mathrm e^{-2}\mathrm e^2\\&=2
\end{align}
$$